# select a string after a substring in an element's class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that contains an input text, to get the input text I'm using the jQuery method `find`.

The input text has a class name like this `page-id-x` with the `x` is variable, so I want to select that number after the substring `page-id`, and this is what I tried :

```
var id = ui.item.find('input').attr('class').split(/\s+/).filter(function(s){
    return s.includes('page-id-');
})[0].split('-')[2];
console.log(id);
```

I think this code is too complicated, but I couldn't figure out some other way to do it.

If someone knows a better way, I'll be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include an example of the element's markup.

Comment: *"I think this code is too complicated, but I couldn't figure out some other way to do it."* You've said the `id` part is variable. If so, then what you have isn't just too complicated, it won't work. Can you please clarify? Perhaps you meant the `x` part is variable?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, indeed, what I meant was the x part is variable

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery, take a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

For your case, you can use `$('[class^="page-id-"')`. These types of selectors (listed on the link above) actually work in CSS, too. (At least most should, if not all.)

To get the number after `page-id-`, my suggestion would be to store that number in some other HTML attribute, like `data-pageID="1"` or the like.

So you could have:

```
<div id="page-id-3" data-pageID="3">CONTENT</div>
```

Then, when you have the DOM element using `$('[class^="page-id-"')`, you can access that number with `.attr('data-pageID').val()`.

Comment: @Connum, I edited my answer, as I realized that I didn't answer the question properly the first time. My updated answer will work for them, but they might have to change their code a bit.

Comment: Not `.attr('data-pageID').val()`, just `.attr('data-pageID')`. Using a `data-*` attribute is a good suggestion; I would combine it with removing the page ID from the class.

Comment: My bad on the `.val()` part. They may need to use `parseInt()` or something similar though.

Comment: Yeah, depends on whether the ID is numeric. But their current solution doesn't use one, so...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the `x` part of `page-id-x`, not the `id` part, is what varies (since that's what your code assumes).

Another way to do it is with a regular expression, but I'm not sure I'd call it simpler:

```
var id = ui.item
  .find('input')
  .attr('class')
  .match(/(?:^|\s)page-id-([^- ]+)(?:\s|$)/)[1];
```

Example:

```js
var ui = {
  item: $("#item")
};
var id = ui.item
  .find('input')
  .attr("class")
  .match(/(?:^|\s)page-id-([^- ]+)(?:\s|$)/)[1];
console.log(id);
```

```html
<div id="item">
  <input class="foo page-id-23 bar">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above makes the same assumptions your current code does, which are:

1. The first `input` in `ui.item` is the one you want
2. It **will** have the relevant class name

I assume those are okay, as your question is asking for an alternative, suggesting what you have is working.

Comment: @naomik: I disagree. Presumably the author is in charge of the markup and knows what's inside that element (remember, this is scoped to the contents of a specific element).

Comment: True, point taken – I do wonder what compelling arguments exist for code that assumes certain structure of data tho... anyway gj ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the HTML markup, instead of using class names, you can use data attributes instead. For example, instead of:

```
<input class="page-id-1">
```

You can use:

```
<input data-page-id="1">
```

Then jQuery can find this element effortlessly:

```
$('[data-page-id]').attr('data-page-id')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find your element using the `*=` selector.

```
let elem = document.querySelector('[class*=page-id-]')
```

Once you have the element, you can parse the id out:

```
let [base, id] = elem.className.match(/page-id-(\d+)/)
console.log('page id: %s', id);
```